# Blender 2.8 Undo like in 2.79

Tags: edit-mode

How to undo last actions in Blender 2.8 / 2.9 without undoing actions in Edit mode, Sculpt mode & Particle edit? I.e. how to make Undo work the same way as in Blender 2.79? It often happens that need to edit something in Edit mode, Sculpt mode or Particle edit & if I don't like the result, then in 2.79 I can easily undo large number of actions at once. In 2.8, undoing absolutely every action is completely inconvenient. Maybe there is some hotkey or setting to undo like in 2.7?